# change gff file format to zff format

Tags: r

I have a gff file look like below and each column separate by tab.

> head(a,5)

```
      V1        V2   V3   V4   V5 V6 V7 V8
     gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler gene 1059 1513  .  -  .
     gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler mRNA 1059 1513  .  -  .
     gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler exon 1059 1513  .  -  .
     gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler mRNA 1059 1513  .  -  .
     gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1| assembler gene 4700 8169  .  +  .
                                                                          V9
                                ID=PASA_cluster_9835;Name=PASA_cluster_9835
                     ID=align_id:87873|asmbl_10255;Parent=PASA_cluster_9835
     ID=exon:align_id:87873|asmbl_10255:1;Parent=align_id:87873|asmbl_10255
     ID=mRNA:align_id:87873|asmbl_10255:1;Parent=align_id:87873|asmbl_10255
                              ID=PASA_cluster_24371;Name=PASA_cluster_24371
```

and I want to change the format to

> ```
> >gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1|
> Exon  1059    1513
> >gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1|
> Exon  4700    5043
> Exon  5520    5691
> Exon  6372    6578
> Exon  7139    7398
> Exon  8010    8169
> >gi|448056666|gb|AJJZ010222983.1|
> Exon  36  948
> ```

I'm very new in r to change format of file so how should I solve this problem. I'm not sure reshape package can solve this program or not. If it can, please give me some example.

Thank you for an advice

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with both the `formats`. It would be better if you have `dput` the data.  Check if this helps:

```
 lines1 <- readLines(n=7)
 gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler gene 1059 1513  .  -  .
 gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler mRNA 1059 1513  .  -  .
 gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler exon 1059 1513  .  -  .
 gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1| assembler mRNA 1059 1513  .  -  .
 gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1| assembler gene 4700 8169  .  +  .
 gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1| assemble exon 4700 8169  .  -  . 
 gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1| assemble exon 5520 5691  .  -  . 

 lines2 <- grep("exon", lines1,value=T)
 library(stringr)
 v1 <- paste0(">",str_trim(str_extract(lines2, perl('.* (?=assembl)'))))
 v2 <- paste("Exon", str_extract(lines2, perl('(?<=exon )\\d+\\s+\\d+')))
 lapply(split(v2,v1), function(x) read.table(text=x, sep="",stringsAsFactors=F))
 #$`>gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1|`
 #   V1   V2   V3
 #1 Exon 1059 1513

 #$`>gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1|`
 #   V1   V2   V3
#1 Exon 4700 8169
#2 Exon 5520 5691
```

Or, if you need it like this:

```
 lst1 <- split(v2,v1)
 lines2 <- unlist(Map(`c`, names(lst1), lst1), use.names=F)
 cat(paste(lines2, collapse="\n"), "\n")
 # >gi|447604937|gb|AJJZ010637342.1|
 #Exon 1059 1513
 #>gi|448181314|gb|AJJZ010120701.1|
 #Exon 4700 8169
 #Exon 5520 5691
```

You can write `lines2` to file using `write.table`

#### Explanation

- Extract everything including a space `.*`  before a lookahead string `(?=assembl)`
- For the second case, we look for a lookbehind pattern `(?<=exon )` and extract numbers `\\d+` followed by space `\\s+` and again numbers `\\d+`

Comment: Thank you  very much but I never use peal before. Could you explain more about perl('.* (?=assembl)') @akrun

Comment: @user3917101. You can also check `<http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html>` and `<http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html>`